# Разбить строку оставив разделители

Tags: c#

Как из строки с предложением сделать массив слов, содержащий слова и пробелы в C#? Например, из строки "I walk with" должен получиться массив, содержащий {"I", " ", "walk", " ", "with"}. Можно ли это сделать при помощи Split?

Comment: `var arr = myString.Split();` Если конечно там нету знаков, если есть, то можно пойти по другому пути - `Regex.Split(myString, @"\W+")`.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4680128/5752652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Regex.Split`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split) включает в результирующий массив все группы захваченные регулярным выражением, которое используется как разделитель.

[`Regex.Split("I walk with", "( +)")`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoRLUB0AKgKYAewBASiQOYQA2AhmAKJkAOYJAzjwJYB7KDyy4AzPgBsKAEz4A7EgDeOJOpSS0MuABYkAWSb8oACgCUKtRps1a5AgGUODfsFMAiAJJIA7kwYAaz83AAsPABokD1MkAGpzD3MCLxEOEgBjd3MxGwBfHDygA==) вернёт то, что Вы хотите получить.

```
public static class StrExtension
{
    public static string[] SplitAndKeepDelimiters2(this string str, char delimiter)
    {
        return Regex.Split(str, $"({Regex.Escape(delimiter.ToString())}+)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Круть, клевое решение. Лучше и проще моего :) Так держать!

Answer (score 5):

Как ни странно, но вот такая вот конструкция справится с поставленной задачей:

```
public static class StrExtension
{
    public static string[] SplitAndKeepDelimiters(this string str, char delimiter)
    {
        var nullChar = (char)0;
        return str.Replace($"{delimiter}", $"{delimiter}{nullChar}")
                  .Split(nullChar);
    }
}
```

В чем логика: мы делаем вот это:

```
return str.Replace("|", "|%").Split('%');
```

только заменив `%` на null-символ ASCII, который 99.99% не будет в тексте встречаться. :)

Проще данного подхода, наверное и не бывает.

## PS: решение user181245 лучше моего, его плюсуйте!

Answer (score 2):

не претендующий на звание "скоростного", Linq-вариант:

```
"I walk with"
    .Split(' ')
    .SelectMany(it => new[] { " ", it })
    .Skip(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - так:

```
public static IList<string> SplitAndKeepDelimiters(this string s, params char[] delimiters)
{
    var parts = new List<string>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        int iFirst = 0;
        do
        {
            int iLast = s.IndexOfAny(delimiters, iFirst);
            if (iLast >= 0)
            {
                if (iLast > iFirst)
                    parts.Add(s.Substring(iFirst, iLast - iFirst)); //part before the delimiter
                parts.Add(new string(s[iLast], 1));//the delimiter
                iFirst = iLast + 1;
                continue;
            }

            //No delimiters were found, but at least one character remains. Add the rest and stop.
            parts.Add(s.Substring(iFirst, s.Length - iFirst));
            break;

        } while (iFirst < s.Length);
    }

    return parts;
}
```

Например:

```
var source = "I walk with";
var result = source.SplitAndKeepDelimiters(' ');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Больше вариантов - тут:

- [Split a string with delimiters but keep the delimiters in the result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4680128/5752652)

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так вот:

```
var separator = ' ';
var res = new List<string>();
var testStr= "I walk d with";
testStr.Split(separator).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    if (res.Any()&&x != string.Empty&&res.Last()!=separator.ToString()) 
        res.Add(separator.ToString());
    res.Add(x==string.Empty? separator.ToString():x);
});
```